# Can one, using CSS, adjust vertical position of elemnts in a web page based on its horisontal dimension?

Tags: html, css, scaling

I am making a web page with a large background image where the position of some elements, like text blocks or buttons, has to be linked to certain parts of the image. Horizontal alignment is fine but I am facing problems with the vertical alignment. Namely, if the window is resized such that its aspect ratio changes, the background image is resized according to the window width. But the vertical position of the elements is expressed in % of the window height (I am using css top property, like `top: 60%;`). As a result, the elements get shifted vertically with respect to the image. Is there a way to adjust the vertical position according to the window width? Then each element would keep its position with respect to the image.

I used code like

```
position: absolute;
left: 30%;
top: 60%;
```

`Left` scales properly here but `top` does not.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Try transform:translateY(0%) so the top:60% stays at the same position irrespective to the Viewport size

Comment: Tried but that does not work, has no effect at all

Comment: The example is  
body { 
  background: url(bgr.jpg);   
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  background-size: 100%;  
 background-color: rgb(181,40,10);  
}  
#firstcolumn {  
 position: absolute;  
 top: 70%;  
 left: 39%;  
 width: 25%;  
 height: 40%;  
  }  

Here firstcolumn is the ID if the <div> element that contains a text. The background image here scales with the window width but the text's vertical position scales with the window height. Thus, if the window's aspect ratio changes, the text will shift vertically with respect to the image